# Что это за компонент?

Tags: java, android, material-design

Это какой-то новый компонент - выезжающая снизу панель? Несколько раз её видел. Как её сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: насколько я помню, в android API целиком такого компонента нет, но похоже на FAB, которая вызывает BottomSheets. вообще на верхнем скриншоте похоже на новый компонент bottom app bar, но он не раскрывается в то, что снизу

Comment: Похоже на Backdrop?